# get time untill given wake-up time with Calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am creating an app where I need to know the time until a given wake-up time, like for example 8:30, so I have this code which works sometimes

```
String hours = separated[0]; // 8
String minutes = separated[1]; // 30
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long timeUntilStageTwo = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

the problem is, if the time is like 1:00 midnight, it still adds up 1 day to the calendar, and then it will calculate the time to the next day, and this will be something like 30 hours.
How can I make it to properly calculate time until next day wake-up time, even when in midnight?

Comment: What is the problem? You set 8:30 am of the next day, therefore the difference from 01:00 am current day is 24:00+(8:30-1:00) which is 31 hours and 30 minutes. Is this what you get?

Comment: yes, I want it to be like 7:30 hours left, just like the alarm works, hope you can understand me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

One way would be to only add 1 day if you're past the original time:

```
String hours = separated[0]; // 8
String minutes = separated[1]; // 30
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if(c.before(Calendar.getInstance()) {
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}

long timeUntilStageTwo = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Another simple way would be to leave your code as is and then take your final value and subtract full days from it:

```
long timeUntilStageTwo = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) % (24*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: 1st solution is correct, 2nd solution is incorrect. In 2nd solution we get the diff right however the calendar event time is still not correct.

Comment: @ManishMulimani According to the question, the OP doesn't care about the calendar object - he only wants the time difference.